# solve time out error in case of large number of test cases while sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

While sorting and then finding the sum equals to a given constant provided in input, for a large number of array elements terminates due to time out.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {

    // Complete the maximumToys function below.
    static int maximumToys(int[] arr, int k) {
        int temp = 0;int sum =0;int counter =0;
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1-j;i++)
            {
                if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                    arr[i+1] = temp;
                }
            } 
        }    

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
           sum = sum + arr[i]; 
           if(sum >= k)
           break; 
           else
           counter++;
        }

    return counter;    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String line, strs[];
        int arr[];
        int len;
        int k;
        int toys;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        line = br.readLine();
        strs = line.trim().split("\\s");
        len  = Integer.parseInt(strs[0]);
        k    = Integer.parseInt(strs[1]);

        arr = new int[len];

        line = br.readLine();
        strs = line.trim().split("\\s");

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
        }

        toys = maximumToys(arr, k);
        System.out.println(toys);




          }
}
```

> expected result- my output actual result - terminated due to timeout

Comment: Try to do it in linear time. Bubble sort is guaranteed time out in almost any coding challenge--if you have to sort, use `Collections.sort`.

Comment: I have tried with Collections.sort. But, it results in classCast Exception. Could you please suggest. My Code mentioned below.

Comment: could not able to post my whole code.

Comment: static int maximumToys(int[] arr, int k) {
        int sum =0;int counter =0;

         List<Integer> colList = 
            new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr));

        Collections.sort(colList);   
        int num = 0;
        Iterator it = colList.iterator();

Comment: hope this would suffice .Please revert inf you need any more information

Comment: `Collections.sort` will be faster than bubble sort, but the time complexity is still O(n log(n)). You need a linear solution, meaning, no sorting or nested loops allowed.

Comment: i mean in Collections.sort(), i get an Class Cast exception, (the code written in my above comment) . How do i tackle this?